# Android Emulator: PC Keyboard keys don't match up

Tags: android, android-emulator, keyboard

Is there a way for me to use my pc keyboard on my emulated android device, but have the keys in the right places? At the moment, "**QWERTY**" ends up being "**',.pyf**"

Is there a workaround (other than using the on screen keyboard)?

Comment: Try check / uncheck keyboard action in AVD manager->edit

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use enter your information using your PC keyboard . Make a new emulator or edit previous one & check that option which is "Hardware Keyboard Present".